# Attempting to insert into a table then update a field within the same stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, insert

I'm attempting to create a procedure that is a basic insert into a table, and then performs a quick update on another table afterwards in MySQL. Please find the code below:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_insertUserSocial` 
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_insertUserSocial
 (
    IN  p_userSocialID            INT(11), 
    IN  p_socialID                INT(11), 
    IN  p_userID                  INT(11), 
    IN  p_referralID              INT(11) 
 )
BEGIN 

INSERT INTO UserSocial
     (
        userSocialID,                 
        socialID,            
        userID,              
        referralID             
     )
VALUES 
     ( 
        IN  p_userSocialID, 
        IN  p_socialID, 
        IN  p_userID, 
        IN  p_referralID              
     ) ; 

UPDATE Users 
SET connCount = connCount + 1
  WHERE UserID = p_referralID;
END 

GO
```

In PHPAdmin it's giving me a syntax error, but I'm not sure where exactly it is? It says line 23, which makes me think it's the semi-colon but I thought that these were needed after an insert statement?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Where do you have the `GO` from?  That's Microsofts SQL Server syntax, not MySQL's. :D

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of problems:

- GO, must specify the `DELIMITER`. [19.1. Defining Stored Programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-programs-defining.html).
- In the INSERT ([13.2.5. INSERT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html)), the `IN` is optional to pass parameters to the stored procedure ([13.1.15. CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html)), but not part of the syntax of the [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html).

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea67c/2)</kbd>